# Function with undeclared parameters having priority over declared

Tags: powershell

I want to create `log` function that works similar to `Write-Host` in a manner that I can give it ad hoc arguments along with some parameters:

```
function log ( [int]$ident=0, [switch]$notime) {

    $now = (Get-Date).ToString('s')

    Write-Host $(if (!$NoTime) {now}) $($args |  % { ' '*$ident*2 + $_ })
}



log  'test 1' 'test 2' #  Cannot convert value "test 1" to type "System.Int32"
log  'test 1' 'test 2'  -Ident 1  #Works
```

I know that I can get undeclared args with `$args` or use `ValueFromRemainingArguments` attribute but that requires me to change the way the function is called as declared function parameters will collect them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off positional binding:

```
function log {
    [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$False)]
    param (
        [int]$indent=0, 
        [switch]$notime,

        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
        [string[]] $rest
    )

    $now = (Get-Date).ToString('s')

    Write-Host $(if (!$NoTime) {$now}) $($rest |  % { ' '*$indent*2 + $_ })
}
```

Note that, obviously, you are now required to include the names of the parameters, but that should be a good thing (it would be confusing to have to know whether `1` is the value of `indent` or the first value to log).

Comment: Didn't know about `PositionalBinding`. Thanks a bunch.